# Commons File Upload Not Working In Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a servlet which is meant to handle the upload of a very large file. I am trying to use commons fileupload to handle it. Currently, the file I am attempting to upload is 287MB.

I set up the FileItemFactory and ServletFileUpload, then set a very large max file size on the ServletFileUpload.

Unfortunately, when I attempt to create a FileItemIterator, nothing happens. The form is set with the correct action, multipart encoding, and for the POST method.

Can anyone assist? doPost() of the servlet is posted below:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // ensure that the form is multipart encoded since we are uploading a file
    if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)) {
        //throw new FileUploadException("Request was not multipart");
        log.debug("Request was not multipart. Returning from call");
    }

    // create a list to hold all of the files
    List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    try {
        // setup the factories and file upload stuff
        FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
        upload.setFileSizeMax(999999999);

        // create a file item iterator to cycle through all of the files in the req. There SHOULD only be one, though
        FileItemIterator iterator = upload.getItemIterator(req);

        // iterate through the file items and create a file item stream to output the file
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            // get the file item stream from the iterator
            FileItemStream fileItemStream = iterator.next();

            // Use the Special InputStream type, passing it the stream and the length of the file
            InputStream inputStream = new UploadProgressInputStream(fileItemStream.openStream(), req.getContentLength());

            // create a File from the file name
            String fileName = fileItemStream.getName();  // this only returns the filename, not the full path
            File file = new File(tempDirectory, fileName);

            // add the file to the list
            fileList.add(file);

            // Use commons-io Streams to copy from the inputstrea to a brand-new file
            Streams.copy(inputStream, new FileOutputStream(file), true);

            // close the inputstream
            inputStream.close();

        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // now that we've save the file, we can process it.
    if (fileList.size() == 0) {
        log.debug("No File in the file list. returning.");
        return;
    }

    for (File file : fileList) {

        String fileName = file.getName();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        List<Feature> featureList = new ArrayList<Feature>(); // arraylist may not be the best choice since I don't know how many features I'm importing
        while (!line.isEmpty()) {
            String[] splitLine = line.split("|");
            Feature feature = new Feature();
            feature.setId(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[0]));
            feature.setName(splitLine[1]);
            feature.setFeatureClass(splitLine[2]);
            feature.setLat(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[9]));
            feature.setLng(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[10]));
            featureList.add(feature);

            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        file.delete();   // todo: check this to ensure it won't blow up the code since we're iterating in a for each
        reader.close();  // todo: need this in a finally block somewhere to ensure this always happens.

        try {
            featureService.persistList(featureList);
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
            log.debug("Caught Service Exception in FeatureUploadService.", e);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "Nothing happens", so the code get stuck at that point and hangs there forever? Isn't it just busy reading the request body? Or does the `hasNext()` return `false` immediately? Please be more specific about the problem. What lines get executed and what not. Oh, your first `if` check isn't returning at all...

Comment: Fair enough. The beginning of the point of failure seems to be the call to upload.getItemIterator(req). A FileItemIterator is returned, but it's "empty": the call to iterator.hasNext() returns false.

Comment: OK, that's clear :) To be sure, the `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req)` did return `true`? You're only logging it in case of `false` and then continuing the code flow regardless of its outcome.

Comment: I added the return statement (thanks for pointing that out). Yes, ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(req) did return true (I stuck a breakpoint and a watch in there to double check).

Comment: OK, thanks. And how about when you upload a small file? E.g. `foo.txt` with a `hello` inside or something? If that also gives nothing, please let us know what you do get when you do a `Streams.copy(request.getInputStream(), System.out, false); return;` at the very beginning of the code?

Comment: Okay, foo.txt still gave nothing, but your other suggestion was interesting. The result of the Streams.copy() was this: -----------------------------133371585111146--
The file only contained the word "Hello".

Comment: OK, only the boundary has been sent. The mime part is completely missing which explains that the iterator gives nothing. What browser are you using? Are you behind a (corporate) proxy?

Comment: I'm using firefox and developing on my local box, hitting localhost. Proxy shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: So other browsers also sends an empty body? Are you sure that the `<input type="file">` is *inside* the `<form>`?

Comment: I'll have to check later, I currently can only use firefox on this box (can't install the IE GWT plugin). Thanks for assisting me.

Comment: GWT plugin? Is this really necessary? Are you sure that it isn't the plugin which is messing things? Just try FF (or IE) without the plugin.

Comment: I'm running in development mode, so the browser gripes at me to install the plugin.
I'm sure the <input> is inside the form. Same problem occurs in FF, IE, and Chrome.

Comment: This is really weird. Try to install a HTTP traffic checker such as Fiddler2 and check if the request body sent by the browser contains the full mime part. If it doesn't, then it's likely a client side issue. If it does, then it's likely a server side issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an incredibly stupid problem. I left the name attribute off of the FileUpload entry in the GWT UiBinder. Thanks for all of the help from everyone.

Comment: Wow, I did also have exactly the same problem and your solution really helps me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are the only request parameters available File items? Because you may want to put in a check:

```
if (!fileItemStream.isFormField()){
// then process as file
```

otherwise you'll get errors. On the surface of things your code looks fine: no errors in the Tomcat logs?

Comment: There is a single file upload field and two buttons (submit and cancel). However, I had forgotten about that, thanks.

Comment: The project is a GWT project running in hosted mode (jetty). However, I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown.

Comment: Ah. Well, not sure: never tried a file upload with GWT. Doesn't it mangle the request in some weird way?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in html form